Why is my weight based bevel modifier only working at a specific angle?
video of problem
Why is my second bevel modifier with a weight limit suddenly not working when I change the angle, and why is the second example behaving literally the exact opposite of the first?

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing. I can't tell at first glance. Have you applied the scale on all these objects?

I would suspect it has to do with the Clamp Overlap option of the Bevel modifier, but hard to tell what is clamped there without knowing the geometry.

Try adding a weld modifier after the first bevel. They are behaving the same way. When the beveled edge gets too close to the other one, the second bevel stops working. Like Gordon said, it's probably because the first bevel is creating vertices that overlap when you move the edges close together and that prevents the second bevel mod from working

@Cornivius Adding the weld modifier worked and produced the desired effect, thank you for the solution.
